tmap -- How can I format only part of a title text, while using a variable as part of the title?
Using the tmap package, is it possible to format only part of the text that makes up a title/axis label/legend entry etc, specifically when part of the name comes from a variable? In my case, I want the scientific name of a species to be italicised in a legend title, e.g. "Distribution of Falco perigrinus"
expression(paste(italic())) works to produce the format I'd like (i.e. "Continents with Falco peregrinus") if all the text is specified:
library(tmap)
data("World")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons(col = "continent",
              title = expression(paste("Continents with", italic("Falco peregrinus")))) +
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)

However, if the text I'd like to have italicised is stored as a variable, then it will return the name of the variable, rather than the value. i.e. "Continents with species":
species <- "Falco peregrinus"
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons(col = "continent",
              title = expression(paste("Continents with", italic(species))))


I don't have tmap installed but try using title = parse(text = deparse(bquote("Continents with" ~ italic(.(species))))).

That'll do nicely, thanks!

Answer provided as a comment by Iroha works perfectly:
title = parse(text = deparse(bquote("Continents with" ~ italic(.(species)))))


I really hope you can find something better, but the following "works":
eval(parse(text = paste0('tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons(col = "continent",
              title = expression(paste("An italic", italic("', species, '"))))')))

Only use this if you have absolute control over the species variable.  The code above is vulnerable to arbitrary code injection.

Hmm, it does but it would get rather messy with the length of all my tmap layers. Cheers
